# merge mutiple files using common column

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting

Say I have multiple files `x1`, `x2`,`x3`,`x4`, all with common header `date, time, year, age`.

How can I merge them to one singe file `X` in shell scripting?

`File x1`:

```
date time year age
101014 1344 2012 52
111012 1200 2010 49
```

`File x2`:

```
date time year age
140112 1100 2011 54
230113 0500 2005 46
```

Similiary for other files `x3` and `x4`.

The output should be:

```
date time year age
101014 1344 2012 52
111012 1200 2010 49
140112 1100 2011 54
230113 0500 2005 46
```

and the similar data from `x3` and `x4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```
$ awk 'NR == 1 {print;next} FNR != 1' file1 file2
date time year age
101014 1344 2012 52
111012 1200 2010 49
140112 1100 2011 54
230113 0500 2005 46
```

Answer (score 0):

Easy, you gonna use the `join` command. Don't remember by heart the argument. See the manual `man join` for more information.

Comment: If you don't remember the argument, please don't post an answer. Answers should actually _answer_ the question.